# how to explain the upright force for the plane?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I remember in the high school physics, my teacher told us that the design of the plane wing is because we want the air above the wing flowing faster than the air flowing below so the pressure above and below will be different so the net force is pointing upright. I am thinking if it is possible to explain this by bernoulli equation? But I soon stuck there because I don't know if bernoulli equation applicable to the case of the air flow in the open region? If so, what cross section we should choose?

Comment: yes it is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Thanks. But that post only telling the reason to generate the lifting force in words. What I am really asking is how to do that in math. Also, I want to know if bernoulli equation applicable to the case of open fluid field?

Comment: [*Look here.*](http://www.av8n.com/) It's a great read, and it has as much or as little math as you could want.